# How to gradually colourize an object in after effects

Tags: after-effects

I'm rather new to AE but I believe I have the rotoscoping under control.
How can I gradually (each frame more) colourize an object in a video. So that at first the whole video is black and white and then one object starts to get more and more colour starting from a certain point and allow the colour to spread back to the whole object.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't give you AE specifics, but one general method would be to have a mono layer and an otherwise identical color layer, keying the color over the mono using a matte layer that you draw on. As portions of the matte layer are turned white, or shades of white, the color layer is revealed.

Answer (score 2):

Set an adjustment layer, mask it to cover what you want, use the Hue/Saturation color effect, and set the saturation to zero...then on your layer push the e key, and then select the stop watch next to the saturation of the effect. go to where you want it in color, and set the saturation amount.  Done